# Archer from Baldur's Gate: Dark Alliance in D&D 3.5

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a friend of mine who will be joining a 3.5 campaign I'm hosting, and the character he's describing to me sounds an awful lot like the archer from Baldur's Gate: Dark Alliance. I know that the game was based off of Forgotten Realms, so I was wondering if that was an actual class somewhere in the books, or if that was unique to the game.

I suppose I should word that as a question: is the Archer from Baldur's Gate: Dark Alliance an actual, playable class in D&D 3.5, or was it specific to the game?

Answer (score 4):

I've only played the game once, many years ago, so I had to do a bit of research to find out about the character... [The IGN wiki](http://au.ign.com/wikis/baldurs-gate-dark-alliance/Vahn,_the_Arcane_Archer) calls him an Arcane Archer, which is a Prestige class in D&D 3.5 - this means you can't start as this class, you have to meet prerequisites by gaining levels in other (base) classes first.

And, as with most computer games, it doesn't *exactly* match the tabletop rules. He's *kind of like* [the tabletop Arcane Archer](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/prestigeClasses/arcaneArcher.htm), but not *quite*.